# Expected Declaration on if statement

Tags: swift

I want a line of code that would change the storyboard whenever a user switches their location to Casablanca but the one I wrote is incorrect for some reason. What is wrong?

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var locationlabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationpicker: UIPickerView!

let locations = ["Select your location", "Casablanca"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return locations[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return locations.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    locationlabel.text = locations[row]
}


if (locationlabel.text == "Casablanca") {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NextBoard1", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide more information on the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the storyboard programmatically, not only perform a segue.

Assuming that you have a second storyboard named "NextBoard1", and this storyboard has an initial `UIViewController`, you can try this:

```swift
if (locationlabel.text == "Casablanca") {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NextBoard1", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
     present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

EDIT - Sample code

Consider this setup:

Main.storyboard has one view controller with custom class `ViewController`, which has one label and one picker:

[image]

NextBoard1.storyboard has one initial view controller:

[image]

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var locationlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationpicker: UIPickerView!

    let locations = ["Select your location", "Casablanca"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationpicker.delegate = self
        locationpicker.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return locations[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return locations.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        locationlabel.text = locations[row]

        if (locationlabel.text == "Casablanca") {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NextBoard1", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Still giving me the error, any way I can send you the code, its only 50 lines?

Comment: Please update the question with this code

Comment: Ok I just updated it

Comment: Right, check the updated answer

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as accepted answer if you can

Comment: Now I have an issue where it shows nextboard1 first instead of the location picker

Comment: Can you create another question for this? That’s a separated issue and is bad to edit the same answer several times